# Why root user needs `sudo` to execute some commands

Tags: sudo, root, su

When I switched to root user using `su` command, I still need to use `sudo reboot` instead of `reboot` to reboot the system, otherwise bash returns

```bash
bash: reboot: command not found
```

Why is that the system would not look for executables in `sbin/` directories for root user automatically?

Comment: Because you do not have in `PATH` of `root` `/sbin`. Add it and voila.

Comment: But why doesn't root have those `/sbin`s by default? Isn't it supposed to be able to execute any commands without `sudo`?

Comment: Second time: check `PATH` variable. Why you do not have it we do no know.

Comment: You *are* able: /sbin/reboot and voila. It worked. The problem is not that you can't execute it, the problem is that your shell can't find an executable when you type just "reboot". It needs to be told where to look for commands. How exactly did you gained the root shell? Are you sure it executed root's shell profile when you entered the shell?

Comment: Use `su -` instead of only `su`. Have a look at man su(1).